# C++ sd-bus source file compilation issue

Tags: c++, systemd

I copied bus-service.c available @ http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html to C++ source file bus-service.cpp. If I compile the .cpp file using g++ compile getting build error can someone help me in overcoming the build issue?

Command used to build:

```
g++ bus-service.cpp -lsystemd
```

saving the the below code bus-service.c file gives no error with below command:

```
g++ bus-service.cpp -lsystemd
```

Below is the source code from the above indicated link:

```
/* start of bus-service.cpp */ 
#include < stdio.h > #include < stdlib.h > #include < errno.h > #include < systemd / sd - bus.h >

  static int method_multiply(sd_bus_message * m, void * userdata, sd_bus_error * ret_error) {
    int64_t x, y;
    int r;

    /* Read the parameters */
    r = sd_bus_message_read(m, "xx", & x, & y);
    if (r < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse parameters: %s\n", strerror(-r));
      return r;
    }

    /* Reply with the response */
    return sd_bus_reply_method_return(m, "x", x * y);
  }

static int method_divide(sd_bus_message * m, void * userdata, sd_bus_error * ret_error) {
  int64_t x, y;
  int r;

  /* Read the parameters */
  r = sd_bus_message_read(m, "xx", & x, & y);
  if (r < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse parameters: %s\n", strerror(-r));
    return r;
  }

  /* Return an error on division by zero */
  if (y == 0) {
    sd_bus_error_set_const(ret_error, "net.poettering.DivisionByZero", "Sorry, can't allow division by zero.");
    return -EINVAL;
  }

  return sd_bus_reply_method_return(m, "x", x / y);
}

/* The vtable of our little object, implements the net.poettering.Calculator interface */
static
const sd_bus_vtable calculator_vtable[] = {
  SD_BUS_VTABLE_START(0),
  SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
  SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide", "xx", "x", method_divide, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
  SD_BUS_VTABLE_END
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  sd_bus_slot * slot = NULL;
  sd_bus * bus = NULL;
  int r;

  /* Connect to the user bus this time */
  r = sd_bus_open_user( & bus);
  if (r < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to system bus: %s\n", strerror(-r));
    goto finish;
  }

  /* Install the object */
  r = sd_bus_add_object_vtable(bus, & slot,
    "/net/poettering/Calculator", /* object path */
    "net.poettering.Calculator", /* interface name */
    calculator_vtable,
    NULL);
  if (r < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to issue method call: %s\n", strerror(-r));
    goto finish;
  }

  /* Take a well-known service name so that clients can find us */
  r = sd_bus_request_name(bus, "net.poettering.Calculator", 0);
  if (r < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to acquire service name: %s\n", strerror(-r));
    goto finish;
  }

  for (;;) {
    /* Process requests */
    r = sd_bus_process(bus, NULL);
    if (r < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to process bus: %s\n", strerror(-r));
      goto finish;
    }
    if (r > 0) /* we processed a request, try to process another one, right-away */
      continue;

    /* Wait for the next request to process */
    r = sd_bus_wait(bus, (uint64_t) - 1);
    if (r < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait on bus: %s\n", strerror(-r));
      goto finish;
    }
  }

  finish:
    sd_bus_slot_unref(slot);
  sd_bus_unref(bus);

  return r < 0 ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* end of bus-service.c */
```

> ```
> /*Below is the error log */
> In file included from /usr/include/systemd/sd-bus.h:111:0,
>                  from bus-service.cpp:4:
> bus-service.cpp:43:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_VTABLE_START(0),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:44:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:44:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:44:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:44:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:44:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Multiply", "xx", "x", method_multiply, SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:45:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide",   "xx", "x", method_divide,   SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:45:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide",   "xx", "x", method_divide,   SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:45:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide",   "xx", "x", method_divide,   SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:45:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide",   "xx", "x", method_divide,   SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
>          ^
> bus-service.cpp:45:9: error: expected primary-expression before \u2018.\u2019 token
>          SD_BUS_METHOD("Divide",   "xx", "x", method_divide,   SD_BUS_VTABLE_UNPRIVILEGED),
> ```

Comment: Did you inspect the preprocessor output? Try `g++ -E bus-service.cpp` to get an idea what the compiler complains about.

Comment: U+2018 is stands "left single quotation mark" and 2019 is "right single quotation mark". Maybe the website you've taken your code from messed up formatting by changing ASCII quotes to Unicode ones?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing SD_BUS_VTABLE_START, SD_BUS_METHOD and SD_BUS_VTABLE_END with below indicated macro, I was able to resolve build issues.

```
#define __SD_BUS_VTABLE_START(_flags)  { _SD_BUS_VTABLE_START, _flags,  .x = {.start = {sizeof(sd_bus_vtable)}}}

#define __SD_BUS_METHOD_WITH_OFFSET(_member, _signature, _result, _handler, _offset, _flags)   \
        {                                                               \
                _SD_BUS_VTABLE_METHOD,          \
                _flags,                         \
                .x = {.method = {_member,       \
                _signature,                     \
                _result,                        \
                _handler,                       \
                _offset}}                       \
        }
#define __SD_BUS_METHOD(_member, _signature, _result, _handler, _flags)  \
        __SD_BUS_METHOD_WITH_OFFSET(_member, _signature, _result, _handler, 0, _flags)

#define __SD_BUS_SIGNAL(_member, _signature, _flags)                    \
        {                                                               \
                _SD_BUS_VTABLE_SIGNAL,                                  \
                _flags,                                                 \
                .x = {.signal = {_member,                               \
                _signature}}                                            \
        }

#define __SD_BUS_PROPERTY(_member, _signature, _get, _offset, _flags)  \
        {                                                              \
                _SD_BUS_VTABLE_PROPERTY,                               \
                _flags,                                                \
                .x = {.property = {(const char*)_member,               \
                (const char*)_signature,                               \
                (sd_bus_property_get_t)_get,                           \
                (sd_bus_property_get_t)0,                              \
                (size_t)_offset}}                                      \
        }

#define __SD_BUS_WRITABLE_PROPERTY(_member, _signature, _get, _set, _offset, _flags) \
        {                                                               \
                _SD_BUS_VTABLE_WRITABLE_PROPERTY,                       \
                _flags,                                                 \
                .x = {.property = {_member,                             \
                 _signature,                                            \
                _get,                                                   \
                _set,                                                   \
                _offset}}                                               \
        }

#define __SD_BUS_VTABLE_END                                             \
        {                                                               \
                _SD_BUS_VTABLE_END                                      \
        }
```